# Wi-Fi disconnects

Tags: networking, wireless, hp, disconnect

i just updated ubuntu at 15.10 and since then i'm having problem with
wi-fi. It is working, but it became kind of unreliable. One moment
it's working perfectly but sometimes it's still loading and all I can
do is disconnect and connect it again.

```
       description: Wireless interface
       product: AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 01
       serial: 5c:ac:4c:7d:0e:e6
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=4.2.0-16-generic firmware=N/A ip=10.0.0.34 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:16 memory:c3400000-c340ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: enp3s0
       version: 03
       serial: c8:0a:a9:f0:8f:71
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8168d-2.fw latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:25 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:c1404000-c1404fff memory:c1400000-c1403fff memory:c2400000-c240ffff
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.10
Release:    15.10
Codename:   wily
Linux martin-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC 4.2.0-16-generic #19-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 8 15:35:06 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hp-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

```
IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"wnet"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: 38:72:C0:8F:C5:DF   
          Bit Rate=65 Mb/s   Tx-Power=14 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-39 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:91   Missed beacon:0
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I've updated to 15.10 and now, after an hour or something, the wireless connection seems to deadlock. It doesn't disconnect, it just stops communicating. I have an Asus laptop, so this probably isn't HP related.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WiFi disconnects for few seconds and resume](http://askubuntu.com/questions/730908/wifi-disconnects-for-few-seconds-and-resume)